# NodeJS - Form-Data Module, POST file with basic Auth

Tags: node.js, authentication, https, multipartform-data

Trying to POST a file (image) to a server that requires it to be formData. Using the form-data module to aid in this. Have been referencing the docs [here](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#request-submit-params-function-callback-)

Using the following code I receive a 401 Error because I did not pass a password; makes sense.

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('image', fs.createReadStream('./my-image.jpg'));

  form.submit({
    host: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/api/config',
  }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  });
```

However, if I add the password it fails completely, and `res` is undefined

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('image', fs.createReadStream('./my-image.jpg'));

  form.submit({
    host: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    method: 'POST',
    auth: ':mypassword',
    path: '/api/config',
  }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  });
```

If I setup the same type of formData in Postman using the Basic Auth, it works.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sending an `user`?, show `err`, if `res` is undefined, then you're getting an error, show it.

Comment: Does not need a user, password only

Comment: `console.log(err)` and show output. Also try `request` as I explained below.

Comment: Error reports

code: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN',reason: 'Invalid header token',

Comment: Try `request` just in case `form-data` is generating an invalid request for some reason. It appears there's an issue in Node 12, as well for some requests: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27711

Comment: Also try calling node with: `--http-parser=legacy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `request` / `request-promise` module, to see if your auth issues are solved.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

request({
  url: 'url',
  method: 'POST',
  auth: {
     user: 'user',
     password: 'password'
  },
  formData: {
    image: fs.createReadStream('./my-image.jpg')
  }
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Error reports code: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN',reason: 'Invalid header
>   token'

Try using the following parser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-parser-js

```
// Monkey patch before you require http for the first time.
process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser = require('http-parser-js').HTTPParser;
```

If you're using Node 12.x run node with `--http-parser=legacy` flag

Also check the following issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27711

Comment: Tried Request and http-parser-js, still no dice. It "works" in the sense that once I added the parser I got a 200 reply. However, it didn't actually take the image and the response include "You have accessed a default HTTP handler. Derive a new handler and implement" in the body.

Comment: So, apparently the server REALLY wanted the image key to be called 'file' and not 'image', which then makes the above work without the parser.

Thanks!